# Why the singular for "j'aime le sport", but the plural for "J'aime les voyages" ?

Tags: pluriel

I'm Chinese, and I'm a beginner in French and I'm puzzled about this:

Why should we say:

- "J'aime le sport", as opposed to "J'aime les sports"

and:

- "J'aime les voyages", as opposed to "J'aime le voyage"

I can't figure out when we need to use the plural or the singular.

Answer (score 1):

"J'aime le sport" is right but not "J'aime les voyages" (This latter is understandable but [lacking in specificity<sup>1</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27aime+les+voyages%2Cj%27aime+voyager&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27aime%20les%20voyages%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27aime%20voyager%3B%2Cc0).) As an assertion of the same type, such as for instance "J"aime les livres.", "J'aime les plats cuisinés.", you'd get your meaning through more directly by saying "J'aime voyager.".

Sometimes the corresponding verb can be used; sometimes the meanings do not correspond; **fairly often it's a matter of idiomatisme** whether you use one form rather than another; I list a few cases below.

- J'aime voyager. (not "le voyage" but "les voyages" if less specific is possible)
- J'aime parler. _ J'aime la conversation. (neither "la parole" nor "l'élocution")
- J'aime penser. (neither "la pensée" nor "les pensées")
- J'aime plaisanter. _ J'aime la plaisanterie. _ J'aime les plaisanteries. (the sense is similar in this case)
- J'aime étudier. _ J'aime l'étude. _  (not "les études")
- J'aime cuisiner. _ J'aime la cuisine._ (not "les cuisines")
- J'aime lire. _ J'aime la lecture<sup>2</sup> (also, but not as specific, "J'aime les livres." (not "le livre"))
- J'aime écrire. _ J'aime le travail de plume. (neither "l'écriture" nor "les écritures")
- J'aime tricoter. _ J'aime le tricot. (not "les tricots")
- J'aime coudre. _ J'aime la couture.
- J'aime la peinture. _ (not "les peintures")
- J'aime l'art. _ (not "les arts")
- J'aime manger. _  (there is not really an equivalent with a noun: "J'aime la nourriture." is not something people would say in French; you may say it in English ("She likes food." or "She likes to eat.") ; in French you have to be specific as regards food ; J'aime les plats turks. _ J'aime les fruits de verger. _ J'aime la cuisine hispanique.)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Modification après considération de la remarque de jlliagre dans les commentaires</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Due to a correction by vaab in the comments</sub>

Comment: Ha! In french, pour ma part, j'apprécie certes la cuisine **espagnole**! La cuisine *hispanique*... je ne sais trop qu'en dire car... je ne la connais pas. Ha! J'aime aussi beaucoup *les arts*. Les arts graphiques, les arts musicaux... (à l'**Art**... je ne connais rien)

Comment: Réédit interdit après 5 minutes... Je voulais dire que l'Art... dans ce cas (dans lequel je ne connais rien) exige sa capitale à l'initiale.

Comment: @aCOSwt Serait-il trop vous demander de faire vos critiques clairement?    « hispanique » déborde de l'Espagne et englobe le Mexique ( parmi d'autre pays), les tacos et le poulet au chocolat!    « arts» est possible sans un adjectif modificateur? Quelle est cette définition de « art » qui prend une capitale? Je ne la vois pas dans le TLFi.

Comment: Not very idiomatic is quite exaggerated: **J'aime les voyages, et je déteste me remuer.** *Correspondance*, 1847-1852, Gustave Flaubert. **J'aime les voyages, j'aime bouger, nager, partir**, *Pièces d'identité*, BHL, 2010.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est un fait, la forme est utilisable mais il me semble qu'elle n'identifie pas aussi nettement  «l'activité »; de nos jours on pourrait même penser lorsque l'on entend quelqu'un dire cela qu'il ou elle a en même temps un intérêt pour les narrations de voyages, en particulier celles contées par le son et l'image.

Comment: Hmm, most of you examples are debatable for me and using a verb is "cheating" : it is out of the question's perimeter and is all over your answer and you infer wrong nouns from the verbs ("j'aime penser", would become "j'aime la réflexion", "J'aime lire" -> "J'aime la lecture"). It would not sound odd to me to hear: "J'aime les études."... etc... And to resume your answer : these are just idiomatic. Which, I concede, could be a very valid answer in itself. An hint for another possible answer: "le sport" dictionary definition is including a "general" meaning. It is not the case for "voyage".

Comment: @vaab The idea of "cheating" has no place here; you are trying to accomplish something generally, however, things are such  -- as is the case sometimes with language -- that there does not exist one unique way of doing them; it is then necessary to consider each particular case and the unique way that applies to it. Also, as you study a form it is often a good idea to consider nearly equivalent forms and the respective merits of the various forms; in my answer, the verb form is almost always an equivalent that is given as a supplement (interseting Ithink) but nothing more.

Comment: @vaab There is something very true in your criticising my answer: the noun that corresponds specifically to "J'aime lire." is "J'aime la lecture.". "J'aime les livres." does not correspond well, it can be interpreted differently even if in  rare contexts, as for instance  in "J'aime les livres, les vieux livres qui ont jauni au fil du temps, les livres neufs qui n'ont pas encore révélé leur secrets." or even "J'aime les livres pour l'effet décoratif qu'ils ont dans ma bibliothèque.". There are certain assertions in your comment that are not clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

- J'aime le xyzt = J'aime le xyzt en général, c'est le principe (abstrait) porté par xyzt, l'idée, le **concept** de xyzt que j'aime.
- J'aime les xyzt = J'aime **tous** les xyzt pour ce qu'ils sont, **chacun**, en particulier.

En ce qui me concerne personnellement, après une vie à aimer **les** alcools... **les** whiskies, **les** bourbons, **les** *cherries*, **les** vodkas... j'en viens à la possibilité qu'en finale... c'est **l'** alcool que j'aime.

Hips!
Pardon!

Cela me fait penser que je ne connais rien de la production chinoise... à l'occase... tu y penseras... ;-)

Comment: In short, yingying, it's pretty arbitrary, so don't fret about it too much :-)

Comment: @GeorgeM : pretty subjective. indeed. Not arbitrary. Arbitrariness is in what is said about. Because what is said about is a generalization and a generalization is always arbitrary.